# Getting a random record with conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

The following code does not do what I need it to do. I would like to return a random design object whose user_id is not 1. As is, the query sometimes return no record.

```
   offset = rand(Design.count)
   @design = Design.first(:offset => offset, :conditions => [ "user_id != ?", 1])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you'll want to do is count the number of elements that also match those conditions:

```
offset = rand(Design.count(:conditions => [ "user_id <> ?", 1]))
```

Comment: Thanks, never seen '<>' before, what is it?

Comment: That's SQL standard for `!=`, however most SQL implementations support `!=`.

Answer (score 0):

if the database is fairly small you can call sample method on the returned array.

```
Design.where(:offset => offset, :conditions => [ "user_id != ?", 1]).sample
```